# How can I embed this snapppt javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm trying to embed a javascript from snapppt.com into a cms page. It shows me in console that the script has been loaded, but there is nothing showing up.

This is the code i get from snapppt.com:

```
<script src='//snapppt.com/widgets/widget_loader/724028e3-d261-411c-8042-c1901fbc8ad7/carousel.js' class='snapppt-widget'></script>
```

Do I need anything in addition to this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use the script and i get error in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function carousel.js:69

I think that you use the code correctly but there is some error in the script that you are loading